# Is or are usage in a particular sentence

Tags: grammatical-number, premodifiers

The number of sticks is/are are 30. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The singular *is* is appropriate here, as it refers to the singular noun *number*. The phrase *of sticks* simply modifies the noun *number*. Structurally, the sentence is equivalent to *The number is 30.*

Comment: Hello jdmc. This question has been asked before on ELU; it's best to check by an on-site search before duplicating (especially basic) work. Yes, it's hard to know what questions are likely to be duplicates when you're new here. The answer is **a lot**.